# Spotify Podcasts: How can I export the data on episode performance / retention rate?

Tags: web-scraping, spotify, podcast

I am conducting research on podcasts and their performance on Spotify. For a new project, I am now looking for a way to export the **listener retention rate** (Episode performance) from one episodes (I have access to the account with the full rights on the podcast).

There is a nice graph in the creator dashboard that lets me see at which points in time listeners dropped out. However, this data does not seem to be exportable. Even Spotify support confirmed that there is not yet an easy way to download this data. However, for my research, I really need to have it in a nice and tidy .csv file format.

How could I download the data under the graphic I see in the dashboard? Are there any workarounds with the API or scraping options?

I tried accessing it through the API and also looked for a button in the download dashboard. Both did not work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.